# Schema builder - how to execute query after create table | Laravel 5

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I have next database migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Ift extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::transaction(function(){
            Schema::create('displaio.ift', function($table){
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('user_id');
                $table->string('address_line1');
                ...
                $table->string('tax_id');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->softDeletes();
            });

            \DB::connection('old-displate')->insert('INSERT INTO displaio.ift (user_id, address_line1, address_line2, address_city, address_state, address_zip, country, first_name, last_name, birthday, tax_id) (SELECT id, address_line1, address_line2, address_city, address_state, address_zip, ift_country, ift_first_name, ift_last_name, ift_birthday, ift_tax_id FROM displaio.user WHERE ift_first_name <> \'\' AND ift_last_name <> \'\' AND address_line1 <> \'\' AND address_line2 <> \'\' AND address_city <> \'\' AND address_state <> \'\' AND address_zip <> \'\' AND ift_tax_id <> \'\')');
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` console show me: `[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7`. Write: `relation displaio.ift is undefined` next to `INSERT INTO displaio.ift`. How can I execute this query AFTER Schema::create()? Is it possible?

Comment: It is, but apparently this table does not exist. My guess is that Schema::create() and insert are using different connections and different databases - I can see you setting connection name explicitely for the insert.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo yes - when I remove `connection(...)` it's working fine. Thank you, I hope, Polish brother :)